# Inconsistent vertical space between `longtable`and a following heading

Tags: longtable, line-spacing

In the MWE, I get a bigger vertical space before the `\section(TWO)` heading than before `\section(THREE)`. The amount of space seems to depend on whether or not there is a paragraph of text before the `longtable`.

Is there a way to fix this, without just manually adding some `vspace` where necessary? I want both spaces to match the one before `\section(TWO)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\LTpre=\smallskipamount
\LTpost=\smallskipamount
\LTleft=0pt % irrelevant, except it makes it easier to see the different spacing

\begin{document}

\section{ONE}

some text

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with some text before it
\end{longtable}

\section{TWO}

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with nothing before it
\end{longtable}

\section{THREE}

\end{document}
```

Illustrative MWE [added by cfr]:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\section{ONE}

some text

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with some text before it
\end{longtable}

\hrule

\section{TWO}

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with nothing before it
\end{longtable}

\hrule

\section{THREE}

\end{document}
```

[image: squished space before section]

Comment: Please roll back if you don't like my edit.

Comment: @cfr Your version of the MWE shows more clearly than mine where the vertical space is actually coming from - but if I had known that, I probably wouldn't have needed to ask the question ;)

Comment: ;) But it will hopefully make the question/answer pair more useful to others, who may not have your knowledge. (I wouldn't know what to do about it, even though I could figure out where it was going wrong. At least, not off-hand.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no paragraph is actually typeset at the outer level, when `\section{THREE}` is found the conditional `\if@nobreak` is still set to true.

The conditional is set to true by a sectioning command and then to false when the next paragraph starts, in order to ensure no page break can happen between a title and the text. Moreover, if a new section title (usually of a lower level) is found when the conditional is set to false, the space between the two consecutive titles them is reduced: this is what happens here, notwithstanding the table in between.

You can set it manually at the end of the `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\LTpre=\smallskipamount
\LTpost=\smallskipamount
\LTleft=0pt % irrelevant, except it makes it easier to see the different spacing

\begin{document}

\section{ONE}

some text

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with some text before it
\end{longtable}


\section{TWO}

\begin{longtable}{l}
tabular data with nothing before it
\end{longtable}\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname

\section{THREE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tested and the `longtable` normally breaks across pages.

Comment: Simple when you understand how this stuff works! In the "real" application I have my own environment wrapped around `longtable`, so I can flip the switch inside that.

Comment: @alephzero Been there, done that! The culprit in the other occasion was `lstlisting`.