# beforeskip does not work with longtable

Tags: spacing, sectioning, longtable, koma-script

Following code snippet:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc, version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-3cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    A \\
\end{longtable}
\section{Two}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    B \\
\end{longtable}
\section{Three}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    C \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

produces following output:

[image: PDF output with longtable]

As one can notice, no **3cm** *skip* has been done BEFORE any section. If, by comparison, I am using **lipsum** instead of **longtable**, thinks seem to work:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc, version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1][1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1][1]
\section{Three}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: PDF output with lipsum]

### Edit

Relates to [Inconsistent vertical space between `longtable`and a following heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345144/inconsistent-vertical-space-between-longtableand-a-following-heading).
Actually, the problem disappears if I use:

```
\csname @nobreakfalse\endcsname
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, to long for a comment, but the same happens with the standard classes:

```
%\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc,
%version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Change of beforeskip and afterskip of \section
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3cm}%
                                   {.2cm}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-3cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    A \\
\end{longtable}
\showthe\lastskip
\section{Two}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    B \\
\end{longtable}
\section{Three}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    C \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

So it seems to be a longtable feature unrelated to koma-script.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that `longtable` doesn't reset `\if@nobreak`. This conditional is used by `\section` and similar commands to decide whether they're called immediately after another (for instance, `\subsection` following `\section` without any intervening paragraph).

The first text paragraph after a sectional title (globally) resets `\if@nobreak` to false, whereas the sectional commands set it to true.

On the other hand, `longtable` doesn't necessarily produce paragraphs and, if so with a `p` column, it does it in a `\parbox` where the `\if@nobreak` mechanism is disabled.

You may want to add `\@nobreakfalse` at the end of `longtable`.

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc, version=last,fontsize=8pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-3cm, afterskip=.2cm]{section}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\endlongtable{\@nobreakfalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    A \\
\end{longtable}
\section{Two}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    B \\
\end{longtable}
\section{Three}
\begin{longtable} {l}
    C \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]